# .NET 8 Blazor WebAssembly, Camera Barcode Scanner Auto-Focus

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, barcode-scanner, .net-8.0

I'm making a new app using .NET 8 and Blazor Webassembly.  I need to use a barcode scanner to read a vehicle number off of a sticker on the vehicle (and then obviously do something with that number... but not relevant for this question).

I was able to get this (*Nuget Package name same as using statement*) to read the barcodes, but it seems really picky as to when it'll actually pick up the barcode...and it doesn't seem to re-focus very well (or at all) as the barcode is moved closer to/further from the camera:

```
@using BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS

<BlazorBarcodeScanner.ZXing.JS.BarcodeReader Title="Scan Barcode from Camera"
                                         StartCameraAutomatically="false"
                                         ShowStart="true"
                                         ShowReset="true"
                                         ShowToggleTorch="true"
                                         ShowVideoDeviceList="true"
                                         VideoWidth="450"
                                         VideoHeight="600"
                                         
OnBarcodeReceived="LocalReceivedBarcodeText" />
@code {
    private string LocalBarcodeText;
    private void LocalReceivedBarcodeText(BarcodeReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.LocalBarcodeText = args.BarcodeText;
        string test = "";
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Is there a working example using ZXing directly, Quagga, or another functional barcode scanner (not QR code...the company I work for needs to use normal barcodes) I can look at?